# AJAX to Ruby controller

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am trying to consume a controller action from ajax by this :

```
var idDocumento = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        url: "%=  document_download_create_company_company_document_path(company_id:params[:id], id: %>" + idDocumento + ""<%, :format => :js ) %>",
                        success: function(data){
                            alert(data);
                        }
                    });         

                });
```

To this controller :

```
  def document_download_create

    end
```

I need to get the parameters in the controller from the ajax call, and make an insert in MediaDownload. I already added the route `document_download_create_company_company_document_path.
So my question is, how should I get the parameters int the controller action, and how to send it properly, because I am getting an error in :

```
"<%=  document_download_create_company_company_document_path(company_id:params[:id], id: %>" + idDocumento + ""<%, :format => :js ) %>"
```

That says

```
syntax error, unexpected ')'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I edited my question, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
<%= document_download_create_company_company_document_path(company_id:params[:id], id: %>
```

Erb is being parsed before the javascript is executed. What's more, it have absolutely no idea that `idDocumento` represents anything - for erb it is just a text. In short - you can't pass javascript value to the erb block. THere is a way around though:

```
var idDocumento = $(this).attr('id');
var pathTemplate = "<%=document_download_create_company_company_document_path(company_id: params[:id], id: :idDocumento, format: js) %>"
var path = pathTemplate.replace('idDocumento', idDocumento)
```

Explanation:

Since you don't know `idDocumento` at the time erb is executed, you stub it with a symbol `:idDocumento`. This will make erb to render:

```
var pathTemplate = "path/to/document/with/id/idDocumento/download"
```

hence, all your js need to do is to replace this `idDocumento` string with the known at this point value.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your syntax is messed up a little too:

```
var idDocumento = $(this).attr('id');
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    url: "<%=  document_download_create_company_company_document_path(company_id:params[:id], id: %>" + idDocumento + "<%, :format => :js ) %>",
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
  });
```

---

**`ERB`**

If you're calling this code in the assets (`application.js`), it won't work. Reason being Rails doesn't run `erb` code in the assets pipeline (because you can precompile it)

If you want to send params to a URL through ajax, you'll be better using either a [`link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) with `remote` option, or using a form:

```
<%= link_to "your_link", document_download_create_company_company_document_path(company_id:params[:id], id: #your_id_param), remote: :true %>
```

Considering your `Ajax` has to be bound to an event anyway, I'd recommend using a link like this as the best way to keep your app to convention

PS - how did you build your link path? That thing is huge -- might be worth cutting it down?